# Recursive Facebook Page Webscraper with Selenium & Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, recursion, selenium-webdriver

What I try to do is to loop through an array of Facebook page IDs and to return the code from each event page. Unfortunately, I only get the code of the last page ID in the array but as many times as elements are in the array. E.g. when I have 3 ID's in the array I get 3 times the code of the last page ID.

I already experimented with async await but I had no success.

The expected outcome would be the code of each page.
Thank you for any help and examples.

```js
//Looping through pages
pages.forEach(
  function(page) {
    //Creating URL
    let url = "https://mbasic.facebook.com/"+page+"?v=events";
    //Getting URL
    driver.get(url).then(
      function() {
        //Page loaded
        driver.getPageSource().then(function(result) {
          console.log(result);
        });
      }
    );
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you faced the same issue i did when i created a **scraper** using python and selenium. Facebook has countermeasure on manual URL change, you cannot change it , i receive the same data again and again even though it was automated. in order to get a good result you need to have access of face books Graph API which provides a complete object of Facebook page with its pagination URL.

or the second way i got it write was i used on click button of selenium  browser automation to scroll down the next page.it wont work like you are typing , i prefer the usage of graph API